# Qt High Score System

Tags: qt, list, qml, states

I'm still quite new to Qt and I want to add a High Score system to my game. I found this file http://grip.espace-win.net/doc/apps/qt4/html/demos-declarative-snake-content-highscoremodel-qml.html which is a high score model qml element. I have have added it to my project but I am at an utter loss on how to implement it. I simply want to know how I can use it to show a High Score Table when my window goes to a certain state. I also want to know how to add scores and close it when the game is restarted. This my seem silly but I really can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the linked file above:

> Use this component like this:
>
> ```
> HighScoreModel {
>   id: highScores
>   game: "MyCoolGame"
> }
> ```
>
> Then ... use the model in a view:
>
> ```
> ListView {
>   model: highScores
>   delegate: Component {
>     ... player ... score ...
>   }
> }
> ```

So by slightly altering the simpler of the two examples given in the [QML `ListView` docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-listview.html#example-usage), we get:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

ListView {
  width: 180; height: 200
  model: highScores {}
  delegate: Text {
    text: player + ": " + score
  }
}
```

Though if you want further control over the formatting of each element of the list, as suggested by the use of `delegate: Component` in the example quoted above from *HighScoreModel.qml*, the second usage example in the documentation shows you how.

Comment: "This means you'll need a remote SQL server" Does it? I'm pretty sure it uses its own local sql database. You certainly don't have to have a database running to run the Snake example (and keep track of high scores).

Comment: @sepp2k: My bad - hadn't read [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeglobalobject.html#offline-storage-api).

Comment: I don't understand how to implement the list view part

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at V-Play Engine for qt-based apps and games. It comes with many components to make mobile development easier.

You can also add leaderboards and user profiles to your application with a few lines of code:

```
import VPlay 2.0
import VPlayApps 1.0
import QtQuick 2.9

App {

 // app navigation
 Navigation {
   NavigationItem {
     title: "User Profile"
     icon: IconType.user
     NavigationStack {
       initialPage: socialView.profilePage
     }
   }

   NavigationItem {
     title: "Leaderboard"
     icon: IconType.flagcheckered
     NavigationStack {
       initialPage: socialView.leaderboardPage
     }
   }
 }

 // service configuration
 VPlayGameNetwork {
   id: gameNetwork
   gameId: 285
   secret: "AmazinglySecureGameSecret"

   // increase leaderboard score by 1 for each app start
   Component.onCompleted: gameNetwork.reportRelativeScore(1)
 }

 // social view setup
 SocialView {
   id: socialView
   gameNetworkItem: gameNetwork
   multiplayerItem: multiplayer
   visible: false // we show the view pages on our custom app navigation
 }
}
```

See here for more information: https://v-play.net/cross-platform-app-development/how-to-add-chat-service-and-cross-platform-leaderboard-with-user-profiles-to-your-ios-or-android-app#add-leaderboard-with-user-profiles